# D3.js v5 Get data from value

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to take data from inside of some circles I've created, code rigth down. The circles have to contain this information, but I don't know if it contains it.

The code of the data in the circles is:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
var year=1970
function typeClean(row){
  r = {}
  r.country = row.Country;
  r.continente = row.Continent;
  r.year = +row.Year;
  r.fertility = +row.fertility;
  r.esperanza = +row.life;
  r.population = +row.population;
  r.region = row.region;
  //return r;

    if(r.year==year){
        return r;
    }
 }
```

Then, I define some circles like this:

```
var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
var chart = svg.append("g").attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
    chart.selectAll("body").data(datos).enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.esperanza))
           .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.fertility))
           .attr("r", d => rScale(d.population))
           .attr("fill", d => colorScale(d.region))
           .attr("stroke", "#FFF")
           .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
           .on("mouseover", function (d) {
               var thatCountry = ...;
           }
      )
```

[circles by countries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQY5t.png)

What I'm trying to do is to find data inside of my circles if I have my mouse over the circle, but when the mouse exit this circle, the hover disapear. Then, with the data, I would like to put a text with the country and the population.

Now, all the code:

```
const totalWidth = 900;
const totalHeight = 420;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 80, left: 90};
var width = totalWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = totalHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",totalWidth)
            .attr("height",totalHeight)

var year = 1970;

function typeClean(row){
  r = {}
  r.country = row.Country;
  r.continente = row.Continent;
  r.year = +row.Year;
  r.fertility = +row.fertility;
  r.esperanza = +row.life;
  r.population = +row.population;
  r.region = row.region;
  //return r;

    if(r.year==year){
        return r;
    }
 }



d3.csv("gapminder_data.csv",row => typeClean(row)).then(datos => {
//Scales
const xMax = d3.max(datos, d => d.esperanza)
const xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([30,82]).range([0, width])

const yMax = d3.max(datos, d => d.fertility)
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 9]).range([height, 0])    

const rMax = d3.max(datos, d => d.population)
const rMin = d3.min(datos, d => d.population)
const rScale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([rMin, rMax]).range([4, 25])

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
                .scale(xScale)
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
                .scale(yScale)
var colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

var chart = svg.append("g")
               .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);
    chart.append('g')
         .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
         .call(xAxis)
         .append("text")
         .text("Esperanza_vida")
         .attr("x",width/2)
         .attr("y",48)
         .attr("fill","black")
         .attr("class","axis")

    chart.append('g')
         .call(yAxis)
         .append("text")
         .text("Fertilidad")
         .attr("x",-78)
         .attr("y",-26)
         .attr("fill","black")
         .attr("class","axis")
         .attr("size",-30)
         .attr("transform","rotate(-90)");


    chart.selectAll("body").data(datos).enter()
         .append("circle")
         .attr("cx", d => xScale(d.esperanza))
         .attr("cy", d => yScale(d.fertility))
         .attr("r",d => rScale(d.population))
         .attr("fill", d => colorScale(d.region))
         .attr("stroke", "#FFF")
         .attr("stroke-width",1.5)
            .on("mouseover", function (d) {
            console.log(d)
           var thatCountry;
            })
```

})

```
Country,Year,fertility,life,population,child_mortality,gdp,region
Afghanistan,1964,7.671,33.639,10474903.0,339.7,1182.0,South Asia
Afghanistan,1965,7.671,34.152,10697983.0,334.1,1182.0,South Asia
Afghanistan,1966,7.671,34.662,10927724.0,328.7,1168.0,South Asia
Albania,1964,5.711,65.475,1817098.0,122.67,3023.0,Europe & Central Asia
Albania,1965,5.593999999999999,65.863,1869942.0,120.09,3129.0,Europe & Central Asia
Albania,1966,5.483,66.122,1922993.0,117.56,3242.0,Europe & Central Asia
Algeria,1964,7.653,47.953,11654905.0,247.3,5693.0,Middle East & North Africa
Algeria,1965,7.655,48.388999999999996,11923002.0,248.2,5916.0,Middle East & North Africa
Algeria,1966,7.657,48.806000000000004,12229853.0,248.9,5478.0,Middle East & North Africa
Angola,1964,7.425,34.604,5337063.0,305.2,4573.0,Sub-Saharan Africa
Angola,1965,7.43,35.007,5431135.0,297.55,4840.0,Sub-Saharan Africa
Angola,1966,7.422000000000001,35.41,5524090.0,289.99,5043.0,Sub-Saharan Africa
```

Comment: You can check if your data has been assigned to the circle object correctly by printing the data to the console, in your .on('mouseover') event type console.log(d) and check what comes up in the console. If the data has been assigned properly you can then use the .on('mouseenter'), .on('mousemove'), and .on('mouseout') events to create your popup.

Comment: And for modify the value of year to update the image?

Comment: For simplicity sake, if you had a button for each year present in your data, you would then attach an event for when each button is clicked. You could then update the graph using '.each' or remove the graph entirely and change the 'year' variable and redraw it using the function you have created. If you edit your question and include the full code and data I'll take a look for you.

Comment: Yes!!!! I've write console.log(d) and I have all data inside the circles. Thanks. Now, do you now how I can take only the values of the circles which I have my mouse over? Another problem I used to have is that if I put the hover for change the circles color, when I exit the circles, the wrong color remains

Comment: That's good :), .on('mouseover', function (d) { console.log(d) }); should return the data of the circle that you're hoving over. Could you upload part of your csv file, it doesn't have to be all of it bust just enough so that I can test your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little difficult to understand from your question, but it sounds like what you want to do is:

- respond to some event e.g. `mouseover`
- change the DOM in some way as a response

So firstly there is a mistake in your selection which is going to screw up the data binding, which is quite important for this. The following line:

```
chart.selectAll("body").data(datos).enter().append("circle")
```

Should read something more like:

```
chart.select("body").selectAll("circle").data(datos).enter().append("circle");
```

Essentially you should be calling `selectAll` for the thing you're going to append. You can stray from this pattern later for more advanced visualization.

---

To response to an event, you subscribe as you're doing, the first parameter `d` represents the `datum` or row of data you're bound to.

```
.on("mouseover", function(datum, index, elements) { 
    // datum can have additional information on
})
```

At this point I would typically manually modify the DOM. E.g. If I want some text to use as a tooltip for example. Note that instead of joining to `circle` you'd have to join to an `svg:g` and append the circles within it (because you can't add a `text` node in a `circle`).

```
.on("mouseover", function(datum) {
    // this represents the element selected
    d3.select(this)
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .text(d => d.name);
});
```

Note that the cleanup is just as simple, on a `mouseexit` event you can strip out all text elements from the `svg:g`

```
d3.select(this)
  .selectAll("text")
  .remove();
```

Comment: @Krakenudo no problem, if that helps I'd appreciate an up vote and marking the answer accepted :)